# Access NUnit Test Name within Class Attribute

Tags: unit-testing, nunit

I'm trying use Data driven testing with Nunit.

```
// I'm actually using it like this:
public class Test
{
    [Test, TestCaseSource(typeof(Test), "TestCaseDataList")]
    public void Test_Sum(string paramA, string paramB, string result)
    {
        int pa = Convert.ToInt32(paramA);
        int pb = Convert.ToInt32(paramB);
        Soma soma = new Soma();
        Assert.AreEqual(result, soma.Sum(pa, pb).ToString());
    }
}

public IEnumerable TestCaseDataList
{
    get
    {
        List<TestCaseData> testCaseDataList = new TestDataReader().ReadExcelData(@"C:\Data\TestData.xls", @"Plan1");

        foreach (TestCaseData testCaseData in testCaseDataList)
        {
            yield return testCaseData;
        }
    }
}

// But i want to use like this:
public class Test
{
    [Test, TesteCaseAttribute(@"C:\Data\TestData.xls", @"Plan1")]
    public void Test_Sum(string paramA, string paramB, string result)
    {
        int pa = Convert.ToInt32(paramA);
        int pb = Convert.ToInt32(paramB);
        Soma soma = new Soma();
        Assert.AreEqual(result, soma.Sum(pa, pb).ToString());
    }
}

[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Class | System.AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false)]
public class TesteCaseAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    private string plan;
    private string ab;

    public TesteCaseAttribute(String plan, String ab)
    {
        this.plan = plan;
        this.ab = ab;
    }
}

public IEnumerable TestCaseDataList
{
    get
    {
        List<TestCaseData> testCaseDataList = new TestDataReader().ReadExcelData(this.plan, this.ab);

        foreach (TestCaseData testCaseData in testCaseDataList)
        {
            yield return testCaseData;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I have `TestCaseAttribute` constructor receive the return of `TestCaseDataList`?

Comment: That's not possible using TestCaseAttribute, if that's what you mean. If "TesteCaseAttribute" is intended to be a new attribute of your own, you would have to write the attribute in a way that it creates test cases out of the excel file. Describing how to do that would be more on the scale of a magazine article than an SO answer. :-)

Comment: Hello. TesteCaseAttribute is my new class attribute xD.
I already create the cases, the problem is how to pass that in the constructor of the TesteCaseAttribute. For now i just return de yield list, but cant do this on constructor :/